# mouseWorld Coordinates Box2D

Tags: c++, box2d

I have one simple question in Box2D:
if you want to get the world coordinates of mouse, this is the function you gonna use in Java:

```
    void update(int x, int y)
    {
        if(mousejoint !=0)
        {
            // Always convert to world coordinates!
            Vec2 mouseWorld = box2d.coordPixelsToWorld(x,y);
            mousejoint.setTarget(mouseWorld);
        }
    }
```

what is coordPixelsToWorld equivalent for c++ ?

Answer (score 1):

Any association between pixels and Box2D positions depends on the graphical program that's using the library.

So for instance in the *Testbed* program (a graphical program that comes with and uses the C++ Box2D library), the `box2d.coordPixelsToWorld` equivalent is the `Camera::ConvertScreenToWorld` method. Whereas in the *HelloWorld* program (which isn't a graphical program but also comes with the C++ Box2D code), there isn't any association between pixels and Box2D positions and there's no equivalent method.

If you're writing your own graphical program in C++ that uses the Box2D library, you can take a look at the *Testbed* program's source code for the `Camera::ConvertScreenToWorld` method to see an example of how to write such a method yourself. You'll find this method in the [`DebugDraw.cpp`](https://github.com/erincatto/Box2D/blob/master/Box2D/Testbed/Framework/DebugDraw.cpp) file.